# Create a payment on Client and execute it on Server

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, express-checkout

I have a website where I want to offer 2 ways to checkout. One with a plain credit card using Stripe (Stripe Checkout) and the other with Paypal.

The way [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/checkout) works is that when the user clicks a button on my web page, I trigger the checkout request which pops a modal and lets the user enter his credentials. Then it sends the data over to their servers to validate the card and returns a unique token which can is used to identify the card. I send the token via an AJAX request to my server and charge that token using my secret key. So the basic flow is:

1. Generate a token in the client side
2. Send that token to the server
3. Charge the token

I was looking for a similar workflow with Paypal Express Checkout but it seems like the only options are:

1. Generate a token and execute the payment in the Client side
2. Generate a token and execute the payment in the Server side

There seems to be no combination of both of them. I want to charge my client from my server as there are several things that take place when I charge the client.

Is it possible, with Paypal Express Checkout, to generate a token in the client and charge it on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create on the client and execute on the server. Take a look at this doc, hopefully it'll help: https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/blob/master/docs/hybrid.md

Comment: Looks promising! I will give it a try and let you know. BTW, they never show any server-side code. Do they have some documentation for PHP?